# Create a div with bottom half one color and top half another color

Tags: html, css

I have a  which I am going to make into a button. The top half should be #ffd41a and the bottom half should be #fac915. Here is a link to the button at present. http://jsfiddle.net/WnwNW/

The problem that I'm facing is how should I deal with two background colors. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do without the need for addition divs or spans? Can I have two background attributes within the same CSS class?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

CSS3 provides a way to do this

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFD51A 50%, #FAC815 50%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFD51A 50%, #FAC815 50%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFD51A 50%, #FAC815 50%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFD51A 50%, #FAC815 50%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFD51A 50%, #FAC815 50%);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WnwNW/1/

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Can you explain to me why you've implemented the background-image attribute five times?

Comment: Because the different browser vendor's can't get along :) The actual spec is the first one. The different browser vendors, however, have their own implementations. "-ms" line is for IE10+ and you can figure out which line is for each browser by looking at the other prefixes.

Here's the [official spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#gradients)

Here's an [Opera blog explaining it](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-linear-gradients/)

Comment: As an aside I would recommend using something like [Sass mixins](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/7846399901/introducing-bourbon-sass-mixins) to avoid having to deal with writing 5 lines of code when you mean 1.


[Prefixtree](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) may be another option  if you're opposed to SASS and just want to get it done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. You can use two background attributes. However, this is only supported in CSS3. That means that two background images will break in older browsers. That being said, you can do something like this.

```
background-image: url(color1.png), url(color2.png);
background-position: bottom, top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

I'm not sure if you can specify multiple background "colors."