# Jquery UI Slider range styling (left, and right as well)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, jquery-ui-slider

Jquery UI slider gives access to class `ui-slider-range` to do custom css on the selected range. Is there an easy way to add custom css (in my case background color) to what is left and right of the selected range?

Changing the slider background color changes both left and right, I however want a trio effect essentially of 3 separate background colors for the 3 divided regions created by the range min/max selectors;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jQuery to add a `background-image` style property to your `.ui-slider`. You'll have to calculate the position of the sliders as a percentage.

For example, check out the CSS

```
.ui-slider {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red 50%, blue 50%);
}
```

Your jQuery would update the style for that specific slider whenever the user moves the slider. Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/86js5pp6/).

```
var myMin = 0, myMax = 500;
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: myMin,
    max: myMax,
    values: [75, 300],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        // Update amount text
        $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);

        // Update left/right color
        var left = 100 * (ui.values[0] - myMin) / (myMax - myMin);
        var right = 100 * (ui.values[1] - myMin) / (myMax - myMin);
        $(this).css('background-image', '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, red ' + left + '%, blue ' + right + '%)');
    }
});
```

Note, you'll have to find a way to initially color the left/right side. Also, there are a few browser-specific `background-image` properties, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7842446/1370556).

Comment: I wanted to add that there should be a better way of capturing the min/max values from within the `slide` event handler. I didn't see them under the `ui` object, though the slider object should know somehow. Using a scoped `myMin/myMax` seemed "hacky" to me =)