# Css Div 2 background colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to make a div with 2 background colors, and I am aware that you can do the 50/50 gradient, but when you go more extreme, say, 20/80, the colors start to blend.

I have looked at this link [50%/50% hard gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842393/create-a-div-with-bottom-half-one-color-and-top-half-another-color)

but, again, when I attempt to change the values to higher and lower, it starts to blend. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Here is where I am trying to implement it: http://codepen.io/jettc/pen/zrOKqJ

```
 percent = Math.floor((time/timerTotal)*100);
remainPercent = 100-percent;
console.log(percent, remainPercent);
$("#circle").css("background-image","-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222222 "+percent+"%, grey "+remainPercent+"%)");
```

Comment: Did we answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The gradient is just rendering how it is supposed to, you just need to change your CSS to make it how you want. To render to solid colors, **both percentages must be the same**.
Here is some different examples of this:

```css
div{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:linear-gradient( red 50%, blue 50%);
  }
```

```html
50/50
<div></div>
```

```css
div{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   background:linear-gradient( red 80%, blue 80%);
}
```

```html
80/20
<div></div>
```

```css
div{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   background:linear-gradient( red 30%, blue 30%);
}
```

```html
30/70
<div></div>
```

```css
div{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   background:linear-gradient( red 40%, blue 40%);
}
```

```html
40/60
<div></div>
```

### [Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/Jacob-Gray/pen/YwKEwv)

As you can see from the above examples, the key is to set **both of the percentages to the same**, so there is no space to blend the two colors. See these two images for an example:
[image: 50/50]
[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you for your detailed explanation!

Comment: @user2608763 no problem :) When you ask a question on StackOverflow, you should accept the answer that helped you the most. It gives whoever posted the answer 15 reputation and gives you 2 reputation(I think?) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222222 "+percent+"%, grey "+percent+"%)"
```

[image]

You have to use the same percentages:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #FFD51A 20%, #FAC815 20%);
```

or

```
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #FFD51A 80%, #FAC815 80%);
```

... the percentages are defining the color-stops position.

More about gradients here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient